# The image of a completely reducible group is itself completely reducible.

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, simple-groups, direct-product

This is part of **Exercise 3.3.12** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3AImage%2C%20completely%20reducible%20&p=10) and [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Image+%22completely+reducible%22), it is new to MSE. *I am not familiar with representation theory nor is that topic covered in the book so far.*

### The Details:

Since definitions vary, on page 15, *ibid.*, paraphrased, it states that

> A subgroup $N$ of $G$ is *normal* in $G$ if one of the following equivalent statements is satisfied:
>
> (i) $xN=Nx$ for all $x\in G$.
>
> (ii) $x^{-1}Nx=N$ for all $x\in G$.
>
> (iii) $x^{-1}nx\in N$ for all $x\in G, n\in N$.

We call a group *simple* if $G\neq 1$ and $1$ and $G$ are the only normal subgroups of $G$. This definition is equivalent to the one found on page 16.

Robinson defines *completely reducible* in terms of $\Omega$-groups on page 85; however, for $\Omega=\varnothing$, the definition is equivalent to saying

> a group is *completely reducible* if it is a direct product of a possibly infinite family of simple groups.

### The Question:

> Prove that the image of a completely reducible group is completely reducible.

*I assume here that "image" refers to "homomorphic image".*

### Thoughts:

I start out by supposing, for a group $G$, that

$$G=\varphi \left(\underset{i\in\mathcal{I}}{{\rm Dr}}\, G_i\right),\tag{1}$$

where $\varphi$ is a group homomorphism, each $G_j$ is a simple group, and $\mathcal{I}$ is a (potentially infinite) index set. Let $H=\underset{i\in\mathcal{I}}{{\rm Dr}}\, G_i$.

I suspect, from experience and $(1)$, that I should aim for

$$G\cong\underset{i\in\mathcal{I}}{{\rm Dr}}\, \left(\varphi\rvert_{G_i} (G_i)\right),\tag{2}$$

where $\varphi\rvert_{G_j}$ the restriction of $\varphi$ to $G_j$.

I suppose there are two stages:

- Go from $(1)$ to $(2)$. I think this follows from the fact that both $\varphi$ and each $\varphi\rvert_{G_j}$ are homomorphims.
- Show that each $\varphi\rvert_{G_j} (G_j)$ is simple. I think that follows from the first homomorphism theorem, since the kernel of $\varphi\rvert_{G_j}$ is normal in $G_j$.

I think I could solve this on own if I could follow steps like this. My confidence is low, however, because Robinson defines the direct product on pages 20 to 21, *ibid.*, like so:

> Let $\{G_\lambda\mid \lambda\in\Lambda\}$ be a given set of groups. The *cartesian* (or *unrestricted direct*) *product*,
>
> $$C=\underset{\lambda\in\Lambda}{{\rm Cr}}\, G_\lambda,$$
>
> is the group whose underlying set is the set product of the $G_\lambda$s [. . .] and whose group operation is multiplication of components: thus
>
> $$(g_\lambda)(h_\lambda)=(g_\lambda h_\lambda),$$
>
> $g_\lambda, h_\lambda\in G_\lambda$. [. . .]
>
> The subset of all $(g_\lambda)$ such that $g_\lambda=1_\lambda$ for *almost all* $\lambda$ [. . .] is called the *external direct product*,
>
> $$D=\underset{\lambda\in\Lambda}{{\rm Dr}}\, G_\lambda,$$
>
> [. . .] In case $\Lambda=\{\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\}$, a finite set, we write
>
> $$D=G_{\lambda_1}\times\dots\times G_{\lambda_n}.$$
>
> Of course $C=D$ in this case.

I'm not used to it.

Moreover, I want to move on to the rest of the book. I've given this problem a couple of days and I reckon that's enough for half an exercise.

The kind of answer I'm looking for is a full solution or, if not, a list of strong hints.

Please help :)

Comment: This is just to warn you that (2) is not correct as it stands, because $\varphi$ could have nontrivial kernel. So it is possible that $\varphi(G_i) = 1$ for some $i$ or that $\varphi(G_i) = \varphi(G_j)$ for some $i \ne j$.

Comment: I think this result follows directly from (3.3.12) in the book, by putting $N = \ker \varphi$, and using ${\rm im} \varphi \cong G/N$.

Comment: Thank you, @DerekHolt. I think I see it now. Would you mind writing up an answer, please?

Comment: For completeness: "**3.3.12 (Remak)** Let $G={\rm Dr}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}G_\lambda$ where $G_\lambda$ is $\Omega$-simple. Suppose that $N$ is a normal $\Omega$-subgroup of $G$. Then $G=N\times{\rm Dr}_{\mu\in M}G_\mu$ for some $M\subseteq\Lambda$. Moreover, if all the $G_\lambda$ have trivial centre, then $N$ is actually the direct product of certain $G_\lambda$. In any case $N$ is $\Omega$-completely reducible."